# HP Microserver Gen10, Marvel chipset, will it work in Raid1 with Ubuntu server?

Tags: hp, raid

I bought a Hp Microserver gen10, but I was unable to install Ubuntu Lts 16.04.03 using two hdd in Raid1 with encrypted Lvm. The install process runs nice, seems everything ok, but the machine doesnt boot at all, the boot option doesnt show the disks or the raid array. The hardware itself seems to be ok, It works if I install the same linux distro to a single disk.
Troubleshooting steps taken:
I tried it more than 10 times, with Efi, with legacy mode. I upgraded the firmware to ZA10A320 from ZA10A290 and tried it again with Efi and legacy. I tried with newer kernel using HWE mode, and I tried with Ubuntu 17.10 too without any result.
I reported the error to HP, they answered that the Raid controller (Marvel 88SE9230) has no driver in Ubuntu, just in RHEL. Is it possible?

Comment: does it have to be raid? Partition(s) from the second drive can be automounted into your file system giving the practical appearance of one drive.

Comment: I know, but my goal is to have a raid home server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver AFAIK in linux but you can setup a software RAID array. I did this for my box and set up Debian Jessie and OpenMediaVault. So far it has run everything like a champ for me but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup *hardware* raid via Marvel BIOS Utility (check docs here https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=1009955119&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c05355808)